# Present Tense In News Titles

Tags: present-tense, headlinese

Why news titles use the Present Indefinite for the events that have already happened? Here is an example (sorry, it was the one that attracted my attention):

> Windsor-area mom dies of flesh-eating necrotizing fasciitis

Why "dies"? Is it a feature of the news language? Or is it a standard English?
Thank you!

Comment: It's a standard headline convention: it's usually shorter (and therefore allows for larger type) and it makes the event feel more immediate and interesting.

Comment: From English.SE [Why are news headlines in present tense if they refer to past events?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/117100/why-are-news-headlines-in-present-tense-if-they-refer-to-past-events)